# how to pivot pandas dataframe with multiple aggregate field and multiple index fields to sumIfs in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like his

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [['A', '1','1', 25, 5], ['A', '1','0', 3,7], 
       ['A', '0','1', 5, 9], ['A', '0','0', 5, 10],
       ['B', '1','1', 15, 18], ['B', '1','0', 2, 20], 
       ['B', '0','1', 2, 60], ['B', '0','0', 55, 60]] 

df1=pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['id', 'groupby1', 'groupby2','sumfield1','sumfield2'], dtype = float) 
df1
```

How can I either aggregate or pivot it into the form that is aggregated by id, and sum up the subfields with 1s in groupby1 and groupby2  - expected df like this

```
id sumfield1_gpby1_equal1 sumfield1_gpby2_equal1 sumfield2_gpby1_equal1 sumfield2_gpby2_equal1

A 28 30 12 14

B 17 17 38 78
```

28 was obtained by summing first and second row where groupby1==1

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: added @thushv89

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple `multiplication`, `concat` and `groupby.sum` would achive your result

```
df_gb1 = df1[['sumfield1', 'sumfield2']].mul(df1.groupby1, axis=0).add_suffix('_groupby1')
df_gb2 = df1[['sumfield1', 'sumfield2']].mul(df1.groupby2, axis=0).add_suffix('_groupby2')

df_sum = pd.concat([df_gb1, df_gb2], axis=1).groupby(df1.id).sum().reset_index()

Out[1574]:
  id  sumfield1_groupby1  sumfield2_groupby1  sumfield1_groupby2  \
0  A                28.0                12.0                30.0
1  B                17.0                38.0                17.0

   sumfield2_groupby2
0                14.0
1                78.0
```

Comment: thanks! so there has to be multiple steps right? if I have 3 or 4 group by fields just extend this accordingly?

Comment: @santoku: Yes. Since your calculation is based on different columns `groupbyX` (X: is the digit), you need to do each group independently.

Comment: great. there is just one issue. I need to sometimes id can be multiple columns too and i need to preserve these columns. I tried to pass groupby(['id','other id i was too lazy to name']) to your 3rd line of code and it returns KeyError

Comment: if you have multiple `id` column, just groupby them for example 2 id columns `id1`, `id2` as follows `.....groupby([df1.id1, df2.id2])...`